# Why PhantomJS not scraping the page it is redirected to?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am scraping http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=XJO

It shows a blank white page at first, in that page there is some obfuscated JS code.

That code sends a POST request automatically, and then loads actual page.

I have this code to follow the redirected page, but its not working.

```
var page;
var myurl = "http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=XJO";

var renderPage = function (url) {
    page = require('webpage').create();

    page.onNavigationRequested = function (url, type, willNavigate, main) {
        if (main && url != myurl) {
            myurl = url;
            console.log("redirect caught")

            // GUILTY CODE
            renderPage(url);
        }
    };

    page.open(url, function (status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            console.log("success")
            page.render('yourscreenshot.png');
            phantom.exit(0);
        } else {
            console.log("failed")
            phantom.exit(1);
        }
    });
}

renderPage(myurl);
```

It only outputs

```
success
redirect caught
```

See my code, why `GUILTY CODE` part is not being executed ... Why `renderPage(url)` is not being called after redirect caught?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding phantomJS doesn't really handle redirects well.  That may be your issue.  You may want to test this in a different way. Or you can use another browser to perform these tests to confirm.  Check out this git issue to see what I mean https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389.